# ServiceReference always points to 4.0 Framework version

Tags: c#, .net, service-reference

I am trying to add ServiceReference to class library which is targeting 3.5 framework using VS2012.
However, VS2012 generates classes which are targeting 4.0 framework.
The problem is that on hosting machine, there is no 4.0 framework installed and I end up with an exception.
Is there a way to tell VS2012 to generate proxy classes which will reference framework 3.5 or somehow update manually generated classes to target 3.5 instead of 4.0 framework?

Comment: Are you sure the project you are adding the references to targets .NET framework 3.5?

Comment: Yes, in project properties, Target Framework is set to 3.5.
When I open Refence.cs I see the following comment 

//--------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34209
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

And this attribute

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]